# Unzip a file using batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

I have a file Nirmal.zip in a E drive
Suppose I extract the basename of the file alone "Nirmal" and created a folder out of it.
Now there exists a folder named Nirmal and zip file named Nirmal.zip
I need to extract the contents of Nirmal.zip and put it into newly created Nirmal Folder.

How to do the above using batch scripting

Comment: Did you try `7z.exe`,  the command line version of free [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org)?

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't include `unzip.exe` or any other similar sort of console executable for unzipping files.  You can script it using `Shell.Application` with [JScript](https://gist.github.com/889769) or [VBscript](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_zip.php), or even [PowerShell](http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-extract-zip-files-using-powershell/) if you wish.

In the spirit of thoroughness, here's a Windows batch / JScript hybrid script that does what you ask:

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: unzip.bat
:: usage: unzip.bat zipfile.zip
:: extracts zipfile.zip to .\zipfile\

:: begin batch portion

@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Usage: %~nx0 filename.zip
    goto :EOF
)

cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%~f1"

echo(
echo Unzipping complete.

goto :EOF

:: end batch portion
:: begin JScript portion */

// https://gist.github.com/889769
// slightly modified by rojo for http://stackoverflow.com/a/27049936/1683264
function unzip(zipfile, unzipdir) {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
        shell = new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application'),
        dst, zip;

    if (!unzipdir) unzipdir = '.';

    if (!fso.FolderExists(unzipdir)) fso.CreateFolder(unzipdir);

    dst = shell.NameSpace(fso.getFolder(unzipdir).Path);
    zip = shell.NameSpace(fso.getFile(zipfile).Path);

    for (var i=0; i<zip.Items().Count; i++) {
        try {
            if (fso.FileExists(zipfile)) {
                WSH.Stdout.Write('Unzipping ' + zip.Items().Item(i) + '... ');
                dst.CopyHere(zip.Items().Item(i), 4 + 16);
                WSH.Echo('Done.');
            }
        }
        catch(e) {
            WSH.Echo('Failed: ' + e);
        }
    }
}

var zipfile = WSH.Arguments(0),
dest = zipfile.replace(/\.\w+$/, '\\');

unzip(zipfile, dest);
```