# Check if a list of files exist in a zip-folder in cmd

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, zip, exists

I'm very new to coding.. I created a command that goes through the text file vollstaendigkeit.txt which contains a list of file names (in this case pictures), eg.

gruwo_1_1_frau.jpg

gruwo_1_1_hallo.jpg

gruwo_1_1_heissen.jpg

...

and checks whether they exist in the same folder and - if not - registers them in another file called missingfiles.txt.

If all the files are in the same directory and NOT zipped, it works fine with this code:

```
FOR /F %%f IN (vollstaendigkeit.txt) DO (IF EXIST %%f (ECHO %%f exists) ELSE (ECHO %%f doesn't exist >> C:\Users\Rebecca\Desktop\test\missingfiles.txt ))
```

**But what I'd like to do is zip the pictures first and THEN run the .bat to check whether they are complete...**

I tried:

```
FOR /F %%f IN (vollstaendigkeit.txt) DO gruwo_pictures.zip list -flat yes|find "%%f" && (IF EXIST %%f (ECHO %%f exists) ELSE (ECHO %%f doesn't exist >> C:\Users\Rebecca\Desktop\test\missingfiles.txt ))
```

but it doesn't work... can anyone help? I'd like to avoid unzipping but if it's not possible I wouldn't mind either.

Thanks a lot in advance!!
Best,
rebwal

Comment: You could modify a Wscript unzip script ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27049936/1683264)), just omitting the `namespaceobj.CopyHere` directive to skip the extractions, and otherwise salt to taste.  Redirect the output of `cscript` into whatever log file you wish, and use `WSH.Echo` or `WSH.StdOut.WriteLine` to control the output that goes into the log.

Comment: Would be easier if you were using a third party zip program

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers! I will have a look at the script @rojo.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me which archiving tool you are using. The code below uses [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to archive the files mentioned in `vollstaendigkeit.txt`, then reports those that do not exist into `missingfiles.txt`.

```
SET "FILELIST=vollstaendigkeit.txt"

7z a gruwo_pictures.zip -i @"%FILELIST%"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`TYPE "%FILELIST%"`) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%%~f" (
        ECHO "%%~f" doesn't exist >> C:\Users\Rebecca\Desktop\test\missingfiles.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi lit, thanks for your answer! The support of this community is quite impressive!

I'm mostly using WinRar but have 7-Zip installed, too. I tried your code, it did not check the zipped files in gruwo_pictures.zip but those that are in the same directory (unzipped). It did not zip them, too. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: I think that I do not fully understand your requirements. How do you "check whether they are complete?"

Comment: Okay sry, let me clarify.. I have a *word list* (vocabulary) in excel with around 2000 vocabulary items. And I have *corresponding media files* = pictures and sound files for each entry. Now, what I'd like to do is _counter-check the (excel) media list with the corresponding zipped media files_ because in the past, it sometimes happened that I changed the name of a picture in excel but missed to do the same for the file so that they could not be found once I uploaded everything in a vocabulary trainer software.And the reason I'd like to counter-check the whole thing with a ZIP file instead of

Comment: instead of simply the media folder on my drive is because all the files are located and synced with Google Drive and I sometimes have sync problems so that random media files went missing in the past. And with a ZIP folder, that risk could be eliminated.

Comment: This answer creates the .zip archive then compares the file list entries with the .txt file. Are you wanting to compare the filenames in the .zip archive with the .txt file? If so, can you use a command line tool like 7-Zip or WinZIP with the command line extensions installed?

Comment: _"Are you wanting to compare the filenames in the .zip archive with the .txt file?"_

Exactly. I can certainly use one of the proposed command line tools. Since I have none of them installed yet I'd be open to either 7-Zip or WinZIP, so with whatevery you're more comfortable with in finding a solution, I'd of course be happy with :-)